# How to automate soapUI api's(services) using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, soapui

[image]

We have a unique ID that i need to pass through the soapui services.I need to give the input data in soap UI. How can we automate this process through selenium Web driver

Comment: I think you're mixing up the purposes of these tools.  SoapUI is for testing an API.  Selenium is to drive a webpage.  If you don't have a webpage that you can supply the id to, I don't see how Selenium will help.

Comment: I'd agree with Chris Adam's statement, This being a SOAP service you can try automating it within SOAP UI itself

Comment: Agree with other members comments. `SoapUI` can be used to automate the API tests. Additional tools such as Selenium is not needed. Here in the above case use timestamp for the unique value.

Comment: Should we automate the soap ui services using java(eclipse) ??

Comment: Purpose of SoapUI is to test webservices. Pupose of Selenium WebDriver is to test the Web Applications.